# Have I missed some information in this exercise?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, notation, hilbert-spaces

I'm doing an exercise about functional analysis:

> We consider $E$ an Euclidean space such that $\operatorname{dim}(E)<+\infty$ and an application $P: E \rightarrow E$ such that a radius $\rho>0$ exists such that $\forall x \in \partial \mathcal{B}(0, \rho):\langle P(x), x\rangle \geq 0$. Above, $\partial \mathcal{B}(0, \rho)$ refers to the sphere of radius $\rho$.
>
> 1. Draw an illustration in 2-D.
> 2. We assume that $P$ does not vanish on $\overline{B(0, \rho)}$ and define $g$ as $$\forall x \in \overline{B(0, \rho)}: g(x)=-\frac{\rho}{\|P(x)\|} P(x)$$
>    Prove that $g$ is continuous.
> 3. Prove that $g$ has a fixed point.
> 4. Obtain a contradiction and conclude that $P$ vanishes. Explain on your picture.
>
> [image]

In question 2, we are required to prove that $g$ is continuous. I think the continuity of $g$ depends on the continuity of $P$. I'm not sure if the fact that $P$ is called an **application** has some mathematical meaning in this context. Maybe I'm wrong, but I think I can not prove that $g$ is continuous with the existing information.

Could you please shed me some light on this issue?

Comment: Please do not copy-paste part of a book, but type it using MathJax. Indeed, answering a question often require copying part of your question, which is not possible from a picture.

Comment: Hi @J.-E.Pin, I take the original screenshot because I would like other users to have a complete view of this exercise. I'm asking a question about the correctness of an exercise, so I'm afraid of mistyping it. I would suggest you to use Mathpix(https://mathpix.com/) which is very efficient in OCR LaTex symbols.

Comment: Why don't you use your recommended software yourself? You are just you getting rid of the work on the reader's back. Moreover, if you are really afraid of mistyping it, which looks to me as a poor excuse, just let the picture as a backup.

Comment: or  detexify ...

Comment: I have retyped the question in LaTex for convenience.

Comment: I agree with you that continuity of $P$ should have been assumed. From the use of the word "application", I would not infer that continuity is assumed; I would infer only that the author's primary language is French.

Comment: Thank you so much for your verification @AndreasBlass :))) You're right, it's French :)

Comment: Hi @AndreasBlass, I've just received a reply from my professor that $P$ is assumed to be linear. With this new assumption, $P$ is continuous $\iff$ $P$ is bounded. I've struggled a whole day but to no avail in proving $P$ is bounded. I don't know how to use the assumption $\forall x \in \partial \mathcal{B}(0, \rho):\langle P(x), x\rangle \geq 0$. Do you feel that the new assumption that $P$ is linear is sufficient?

Comment: @Akira I'd understand "Euclidean space" as implying finite-dimensional, in which case all linear transformations are bounded. (Infinite-dimensional analogs of Euclidean spaces would usually be called Hilbert spaces, not Euclidean spaces.)

Comment: Hi @AndreasBlass, my professor just sent me an email in which he wrote "I wrote something stupid. P is not linear because it would vanish at 0. Use the indication to prove first that P is continuous." I'm very confused :(((

Comment: @Akira I don't know what your professor means by "the indication".  Without linearity, I don't see anything in the question that would imply continuity.

Comment: Thank you so much @AndreasBlass for your keen help! I got your point. This is a badly-written question. I guess he meant "the indication" by $\forall x \in \partial \mathcal{B}(0, \rho):\langle P(x), x\rangle \geq 0$.

Comment: It "the indication" is what you suggest, then it doesn't imply continuity.